# Installing ubuntu in a lenovo thinkpad 490s?

Tags: lenovo

I normally work with ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I would like to know  if someone has already istalled ubuntu  in a thinkpad 490s . To know if there is any problem with drivers or any other compatibility issues

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rely on others.

It's easy to try Ubuntu on any device using Live CD. You can try Ubuntu without installing it.

Try Ubuntu through [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)

Comment: Yes of course, I will install ubuntu on that machine. I just wanted to know in advance if someone had done it before, so I can know if I will encounter some problem. So I can take advance from other people experience  ^_^